# that with verb after it

Tags: grammar

Why do we use the Verb without 's' after 'that' in this case? I've met this one in discord's description.

> Discord is the easiest way to communicate over voice, video, and text, whether you’re part of a school club, a nightly gaming group, a worldwide art community, or just a handful of friends ***that want to*** hang out.

In my language, in such cases 'that' becomes a subject, so I'd write '...that wants to...'

Comment: Because "friends" is plural.  A handful of "friends who want to hang out."

Comment: *What happens in other languages stays in other languages*. **That** here refers to **friends** which is *plural*.

Comment: In such cases, _that_ becomes a subject in English, too. But it's a relative pronoun (equivalent to _who_ in this case), and relative pronouns are variable because they refer to the noun they modify. In this case, that's _friends_, which is plural.  The **relative pronoun** _that_ does not have a plural form (though the **demonstrative pronoun** _that_ does have a plural form, _those_), so it can represent either singular or plural, depending on the noun it modifies. Thus the verb in the relative clause is plural, because _that_ is plural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Words like "that", "which", and "who" don't have any intrinsic plurality, they inherit it from their antecedents:

- the box *that is* on the table
- the boxes *that are* on the table

Interestingly, the example in the question could in theory be correct either way:

- a handful of friends that want to hang out
- a handful of friends that wants to hang out

with the second case having "that" refer to "handful" rather than to "friends".
That *would* be somewhat awkward and unusual though.
It might be more common if the word "group" were used rather than "handful".

Another example would be:

- a quorum of judges that find him guilty (each judge finds)
- a quorum of judges that finds him guilty (the quorum finds)